# Is there a name for the function $f(x):=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}(1-2\operatorname{mod}(x,1))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have this younger friend who is currently taking AP Precalculus in high school. One of the things that they told me that they like to do is look ahead in their homework (since all of their lessons and homework are on an online resource that this friend has been using since late elementary school) and recently asked me if there was a way to recreate a function that they had seen from a later lesson. Now, I sadly seem to have lost said screenshot of the graph, however, I was able to recreate said graph. If it is important, here are my steps of how I recreated the graph:

---

> Note: Sorry for the "Desmos-speak" per se, I recreated the graph using Desmos and I just wanted to write my steps with how I inputted it originally.

The first thing to note is that the graph looked like the [Sawtooth wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), so the first thing we can note is that the graph is going to involve$$\operatorname{Sawtooth}(x):=\operatorname{mod}(x,1)$$somehow. Now, the second thing that I noticed is that$$\operatorname{min}(f(x))=-1,x=1+2n,n\in\mathbb Z,\operatorname{max}(f(x))=1,x=2n,n\in\mathbb Z$$so we have that the function $(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ may have something to do with it, and that we will have to multiply our Sawtooth function by $2$. Now, the reason we will want $(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ instead of $(-1)^x$ is because the latter is not defined over the reals for $x\not\in\mathbb Z$. Now from here, I don't exactly remember *how* I went about rearranging the functions, but ultimately I got the function$$(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}(1-2\operatorname{mod}(x,1))$$as you can see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eojxsfcmyo). Now, here is a brief overview of the function:

> Domain: $(-\infty,\infty)$
>
> Range: $[-1,1]$
>
> This function is an **even** function. ($f(-x)=f(x)$)
>
> This function can also be represented as $f(x)=\cos(\pi\lfloor x\rfloor)(1-2\operatorname{mod}(x,1))$

---

#### My question

---

Is there a name for this function? This is a really cool function, and it would really be interesting if it did end up having a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observe is called the [Triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave). However, it is more commonly defined as an absolute value of a shifted sawtooth wave. Interestingly, the derivative of this is the [Square wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave).

---

Edit: There is a function that looks similar
$$\arcsin(\sin(x))$$
It looks like:[image]

I guess now you know what to do next ($\arctan(\tan(x))$, $\text{arccsc}(\csc(x))$, etc.)